# Installing XSP CentOS

Tags: linux, mono, centos, xsp

Trying to install xsp-2.10.2.
Has been working fine, now gives me this error on a new install

**Edit:** I've installed Libgdiplus and Mono 3.0.1 from source, now trying to do the same with xsp4.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
make ; make install

Making install in Mono.WebServer
mkdir: cannot create directory `2.0': File exists
GMCS  /out:2.0/Mono.WebServer2.dll
/usr/local/bin/mcs: line 2: /usr/local/bin/mono: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mcs: line 2: exec: /usr/local/bin/mono: cannot execute: No such file or 
directory
make[2]: *** [2.0/Mono.WebServer2.dll] Error 126
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you try removing the already existing '2.0' directory, or setting another path in your 'out:' parameter? Did you check that your 'mono' binary exists as '/usr/local/bin/mono' ? When you say that it was working fine before, are you talking about the same installation on the same machine?

Comment: It's the same machine, with an Identical installation. I just had to restart. I'm an ASP.NET developer with limited knowledge of linux. I've gotten this to work in Ubuntu and OpenSuse. But we're moving our site to CentOS to package with FreePBX. How do I set another path in the out: param?

Comment: Does the binary /usr/local/bin/mono exists? It should, since you say you have installed mono 3.0.1 from source. If not, what does the 'which mono' command return?

Comment: it returns /opt/mono/bin/mono

Comment: and does '/usr/local/bin/mcs' exist? If yes, it looks like your installation is messy since you have some packages in /usr/local and others inside /opt. Is there a previous mono installation on this machine?

Comment: It does exist, I had tried installing Mono 3.0.3 to resolve some issues with Linux .dll's not being on 3.0.1 that I needed. I then Ran "mono --version" and got nothing (because I hadn't included it in the path) unknowingly I just assumed it wasn't working so I used an earlier version (3.0.1)

Comment: Should I just start over? or can I remove the old installation

Comment: you should remove the unused version, but I hope it doesn't conflict with the 'new' installation. To remove the old one, ga back in its source directory and run 'make uninstall'

Comment: I had just done that, installing the new version now. Hoping that will clear it up. Thank you for your time, and I'll let you know how it goes